# Docker : Dockerfile can't execute COPY

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

I ve to build a docker images .
Inside my repositiory , i ve those files :

- Dockerfile
- docker-prompt

My Dockerfile is  :

```
FROM fortio/fortio:1.3.1 as fortiobuild

FROM docker:stable-dind

RUN apk add --no-cache tcpdump apache2-utils lynx git tmux py2-pip apache2-utils vim build-base gettext-dev curl bash-completion bash util-linux jq openssh openssl tree python python-dev py-pip libffi-dev openssl-dev libgcc nfs-utils

ENV COMPOSE_VERSION=1.24.1
RUN pip install docker-compose==${COMPOSE_VERSION}
RUN mkdir /etc/bash_completion.d \
    && curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/cli/master/contrib/completion/bash/docker -o /etc/bash_completion.d/docker \
    && sed -i "s/ash/bash/" /etc/passwd

RUN rm /sbin/modprobe && echo '#!/bin/true' >/sbin/modprobe && chmod +x /sbin/modprobe

COPY ["docker-prompt", "sudo", "/usr/local/bin/"]
```

I ve run this cmd :

docker build -t "myImage"

but if fails throwing this :

> Step 8/8: COPY ["docker-prompt", "sudo", "/usr/local/bin/"] COPY
>   failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder273771066/sudo: no such
>   file or directory

Since it's not clear what is the problem ,

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: Are you trying to copy `sudo` to `/usr/local/bin` inside the image? If not, why are you using `sudo` here?

Answer (score 2):

COPY command work with source and destination only, if you want to own file to `sudo` then you need to use `--chown`. otherwise the copy command will consider the `Sudo` as the source path.

**COPY**

COPY has two forms:

```
COPY [--chown=<user>:<group>] <src>... <dest>
COPY [--chown=<user>:<group>] ["<src>",... "<dest>"] (this form is required for paths containing whitespace)
```

**Note:**

> The --chown feature is only supported on Dockerfiles used to build
>   Linux containers, and will not work on Windows containers. Since user
>   and group ownership concepts do not translate between Linux and
>   Windows, the use of /etc/passwd and /etc/group for translating user
>   and group names to IDs restricts this feature to only be viable for
>   Linux OS-based containers.

I assume that you are looking for a way like

```
COPY --chown=root:root docker-prompt /usr/local/bin/
```